sshd Match on the type of pubkey being use by the authenticating user (Match PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms)
I want to detect what type of ssh pubkey is being used by a user and do a Match Statement on it in sshd_config.
The goal is to prevent using pam if a Secure Key (https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR) was used or another type of public key.
I saw in https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match the Match attribute PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms. But when I use it like :
Match PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com

It makes this error when I try to restart sshd:
Apr 10 12:59:42 ssh sshd[67517]: Unsupported Match attribute PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
Apr 10 12:59:42 ssh sshd[67517]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 136: Bad Match condition

Have you a solution to do what I want ?

PubkeyAcceptedAlgoritms is not a Match attribute. The list you found is of settings that can be changed within a Match section, but the only things that can be matched are:

The available criteria are User, Group, Host, LocalAddress, LocalPort, RDomain, and Address

OpenSSH doesn't really support this kind of complex logic for authentication. I think, though, that in recent versions it sets a special PAM environment variable for PAM modules to get information about earlier authentication mechanisms, so in theory you could require "publickey + pam" but with a specific PAM stack that automatically succeeds if it sees that a hardware key was used, but proceeds with pam_unix otherwise.

According to the manual for Match directive:

The available criteria are User, Group, Host, LocalAddress, LocalPort, RDomain, and Address

This are criteria for the first condition, then you can use PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms. There's a logical AND between all conditions listed in the block:
Match User root
  PasswordAuthentication no
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com

